# Vague SQLite3 Error Youtube queries

Tags: ruby, sqlite, youtube

I have coded an app in ruby which queries the youtube website for some keywords which are taken from a specific db. After the youtube query is done the resulted videos' id and title are inserted into 2 different dbs. I have run the code and I got this exception:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize': near "'tag:youtube.com,2008:video:3taEuL4EHAg'": syntax error (SQLite3::SQLException)
```

Is this error caused by invalid characters in my queries? Should the SQLite gem that I used handle these?

If you need the code here it is:

```
require "sqlite3"
require "youtube_it"

database = SQLite3::Database.new("data.db")
client = YouTubeIt::Client.new(:dev_key =>"myyoutubekey")

result = database.query("SELECT `keyphrase` FROM `keyphrases`")
result.each do |array|
  array.each do |result|
    results = client.videos_by(:query => "#{result}", :page => 1, :per_page => 10)
    results.videos.each do |videoone|
      database.query("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO `videos` (videoID,cachedTitle) VALUES ('#{videoone.video_id}','videoone.title')")

      rezultat = database.query("SELECT `id` FROM `keyphrases` WHERE `keyphrase` = '#{result}' ")
      rezultat.each do |n|
        id =  n.to_s.delete("[").delete("]").to_i
        database.query("INSERT INTO `keyphrase2videos` (keyphraseID,videoID) VALUES ('#{id}','#{videoone.video_id}'")
      end

    end

  end

end
p "Recored Entered"
```

Comment: Include the code in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a " ) " in the VALUES clause